# Cannot find the cookies in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am creating a web page with .net 2.0 and I want to check if it is the first time visit for the user.

I am using the code block in pageload():

```
String CookieName = "Cookie";
String CookieValue = "TEST";
if (Request.Cookies[CookieName] != null)
{
Label3.Visible = true;
if (Request.Cookies[CookieName].Value == CookieValue)
{
    Label3.Text = "Cookie already exists: " + Request.Cookies[CookieName].Value.ToString();
}
else 
    Label3.Text = "Cookie var içerisinde: " + Request.Cookies[CookieName].Value.ToString();
}
else
{
Label3.Visible = true;
HttpCookie MyCookie=new HttpCookie(CookieName,CookieValue);
Response.Cookies.Add(MyCookie);
Label3.Text = "Cookie created. " + Request.Cookies[CookieName].Value.ToString();
}
```

Everything seems to be working, as I run the code "Label3" becomes "Cookie created. Cookie". And after another postback "Label3" becomes "Cookie already exists. Cookie" as it should be.

But I couldn't find my cookies anywhere in my local harddrive.(even if I didn't end the session)

And after ending session and re-run the code, it starts again with "Cookie created. Cookie" which means it couldn't find the previous cookie.

It is obvious that something is missing. I tried to add expry date and path to the cookie. None of them worked for me.

Thank you in advance.

Cagri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I couldn't find my cookies anywhere in my local harddrive.(even if I didn't end the session)

If you have Chrome, and why don't you :), use it's built-in Dev tools <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> and select the `Resources` tab and boom! not just *cookies*!:

[image: Chrome dev tools]

If you look above, in the `Expires` column, you'll see one cookie expires at the end of the browser `Session`, while the other has a set Date.

The cookies you are creating above are `Session` (dies after browser close).

If you want to them to be persistent and survive a browser close, define `Expires` property like so:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(CookieName, "hello persistent") { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) });
```

Hth...